# Example of browser/system where requestAnimationFrame is called other than 60fps

Tags: javascript, html

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame referring to `requestAnimationFrame`

> The number of callbacks is usually 60 times per second, but will generally match the display refresh rate

I've not managed to find a system that runs at something other than 60fps. If the Javascript is busy, then I can certainly get it to be less, but only in that case.

Is there a system that, if there are enough resources, runs `requestAnimationFrame` at something other than 60fps?

Comment: I think the next part of that sentence is telling: _"but will generally match the display refresh rate in most web browsers as per W3C recommendation"_ which means it's not matching the display refresh rate, but rather the rate that browsers (which adhere to W3C recommendations) repaint themselves.  I guess this then turns into a wider question of "when/why would a browser not repaint at the w3c recommended rate of 60fps"

Comment: It also has something to do with your monitors' max refresh rate, most monitors don't go about 60FPS in the first place.